# preg_replace to turn underscore to space except when underscore is part of a given pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm trying to take a string such as:

> $search = "Bob Loblaw + Mark Hamill RT45_part12 foo_092344"

and remove all non alphanumeric characters except when the underscore is located in **RT45_part12**.

The result I want should be:

"Bob Loblaw Mark Hamill RT45_part12 foo 092344"

> preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/", ' ', $search)

The regex to find RT45_part12 is

> \b[a-zA-Z]{2,4}[0-9]{1,5}_part[0-9]{1,5}\b

I can't figure out how to combine these two so that it skips over the underscore that is in the RT45_part12 but replace the one after derrick. Do I need to use the lookahead, lookbehind features?

Answer (score 0):

Is that enough restrictive?

```
echo preg_replace ( "~[^\w ]++|_(?!part\d{1,5}\b)~i", " ", $mystring);
```

But if you want to be sure, use that:

```
echo preg_replace ( "~[^\w ]++|(\b[a-z]{2,4}\d{1,5}_part\d{1,5}\b)|_~i", "$1 ", $mystring);
```

Comment: What does ++ do in this regex?

Comment: it informs the regex engine that there s no need backtracking in this part of the pattern

Comment: This worked great! Thank you. I can't upvote because I have I have low rep :/ I'm new to regex and loving how powerful it is. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: denizb - you should be able to "accept" the answer, since it is your question, and it is the proper thing to do here if it solved your problem -- that way other people who have a similar problem will know that this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

hope this help

```
$search = "Bob Loblaw + Mark Hamill RT45_part12 foo_092_34_4";

echo preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]|(RT45_part12)/", '$1', $search);

//Bob Loblaw  Mark Hamill RT45_part12 foo092344
```

OR

```
echo preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]|([a-zA-Z]{2,4}[0-9]{1,5}_part[0-9]{1,5})/", '$1', $search);
```

update  (non alphanumeric characters to space) ( it only work on have space after RT45_part12)

```
echo preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]|([a-zA-Z]{2,4}[0-9]{1,5}_part[0-9]{1,5}) /", '$1 ', $search);
```

Comment: This is almost right, and I'm trying to see how it's working. But I need it to replace underscore with space unless it's in the form RT45_part12. So in this situation, everything is right, except foo92344 should have a space between foo and 092344 (while keeping the underscore in RT45_part12)

Comment: foo_92344 become foo 92344 ,,  if Bob_Loblaw then ??